# Remove CSS pseudo element from jQuery form function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I developed a contact form for a website.

The field where users enter their message (a `textarea` box) has a jQuery character counter attached to it.

[image]

When the message is sent, an AJAX script refreshes the form and displays a success message.

[image]

All good so far.

---

**The problem starts here:**

When the user is entering their message and begins to reach the character limit, a warning notice appears, generated as a CSS pseudo element.

[image]

When the user exceeds the limit, a restriction notice appears, also generated by CSS.

[image]

---

**The problem**

When the user sends the message, while the warning notice is displayed, the warning notice won't leave after the page refresh.

[image]

This would also be a problem with the restriction notice, but another function disables the send button in this condition, so the form won't send when the counter is in negative territory.

I'm looking for a clean and simple function to integrate with my existing code that will remove the "approaching limit" pseudo element after the form is sent. Thank you.

```js
// text area character counter
// displays total characters allowed
// displays warning at defined count (currently 150)
// disables submit button when < 0
// max characters that can be input set by maxlength attribute in HTML
(function($) {

    $.fn.charCount = function(submit, options){

        this.submit = submit;

        // default configuration properties
        var defaults = {    
            allowed: 1250,      
            warning: 150,
            css: 'counter',
            counterElement: 'span',
            cssWarning: 'warning',
            cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
            counterText: ''
        }; 
    
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        function calculate(obj,submit){
        
            submit.attr("disabled", "disabled");

            var count = $(obj).val().length;
            var available = options.allowed - count;
            if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
            }
            if(available < 0){
                $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
            } else {
                $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
                submit.removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            
            $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
        };
        
        this.each(function() {              
            $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
            
            calculate(this, submit);

            $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this,submit)});
            $(this).change(function(){calculate(this,submit)});
        });

    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#modal-contact-form-message").charCount($("#submit_cform"));
});
```

```css
/* textarea and character counter */

.modalDialog form > #counter-container {}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container > .counter {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #ccc;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif   
}
.modalDialog form > #counter-container .warning {
    color: orange;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .warning::after {
    content: " approaching limit";
    font-size: 1em;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .exceeded {
    color: red;
}

.modalDialog form > #counter-container .exceeded::after {
    content: " form won't submit";
    font-size: 1em;
}


/* success and error messages */

#modal-contact-form-responses,
#modal-subscription-form-messages {
    min-height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
    margin: 5px 0; 
    font-size: .9em;
}

.success {
    color: black;
    background-color: #dff2bf;
}

.error {
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffbaba;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="modal-contact-form">

  <div>
    <label for="modal-contact-form-name">Name <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name_cform" id="modal-contact-form-name" maxlength="75" required>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="modal-contact-form-email">E-mail <span>*</span></label>
    <input type="email" name="email_cform" id="modal-contact-form-email" maxlength="75" required>
  </div>

  <div id="subject-line">
    <label for="modal-contact-form-subject">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject_cform" id="modal-contact-form-subject" maxlength="75">
  </div>

  <div id="counter-container">
    <label for="modal-contact-form-message">Message <span>*</span></label>
    <textarea name="message_cform" id="modal-contact-form-message" maxlength="1500" cols="25" rows="5" required></textarea>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="formtarget_cform" value="modal" id="modal-contact-form-hidden">

  <button type="submit" name="submit_cform" id="modal-contact-form-submit">Send Message</button>

  <p id="modal-contact-form-responses"></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the ajax success call callback, after clearing the value of the `textarea`, you can trigger a change event on the `textarea`. This will in turn trigger `.charCount()` to reset everything back to defaults. Try this

```
<!-- AJAX form messaging -->
<script>            
    $(function() {

        // get the form
        var form = $('#modal-contact-form');

        // get the messages element
        var formMessages = $('#modal-contact-form-responses');

        // set up event listener for contact form
        $(form).submit(function(e) {
            // disable html submit button
            e.preventDefault();

            // serialize form data
            var formData = $(form).serialize();

            // submit form using AJAX
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(form).attr('action'),
                data: formData
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                // make sure formMessages element has 'success' class
                $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
                $(formMessages).addClass('success');

                // set message text
                $(formMessages).text('Your message has been sent. Thank you!');

                // clear form
                $('input, textarea').val('');
                $("#modal-contact-form-message").trigger('change');
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                // make sure formMessages element has 'error' class
                $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
                $(formMessages).addClass('error');

                // set the message text
                $(formMessages).text('Input error. Please review and re-submit.');
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class to hide these elements. On submit, add this class.

```
.modalDialog form > #counter-container.is-submitting .warning::after,
.modalDialog form > #counter-container.is-submitting .exceeded::after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```
$("#counter-container").addClass("is-submitting");
```

---

**OR**

Just remove these warning/error classes on submit since they must be present for the messages to show up

Comment: Won't your solution hide the notices should the user send another message?